# How do I get Ajax working with a Bookmarklet and bypass the Javascript Same Origin Policy?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, bookmarklet

I am trying to write a Bookmarklet and the goal is to be able to submit information from any site X (the origin page they are on when clicking the bookmarklet) to my site's servers while staying on site X.

Ideally, I would be able to send a response back and have it pop up somewhere but this is not necessary.

I keep running into the issue of the same origin policy -- that from site X, XMLHttpRequests can only be initiated with site X's domain.

Does anyone know of a way around this (or a tutorial they can point me to)? some Ajax with a Bookmarklet?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

You can perform cross domain ajax request (send using GET and receive the data as JSON) using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Answer (score 2):

The bookmarklet that you load can POST data to your server from the host page. This is strange, but only Javascript is restricted by the Same Origin Policy.
Making `GET` or `POST` calls to another server work fine.

The bookmarklet can inject a hidden `IFRAME` in the host page , with a `src` attribute like `http://yourdomain.com/listen`.

Then build a `FORM` with the attribute:`target` pointing to that `IFRAME`.
And finally submit the form to `POST` the data.

The sad news, is SOP won't let you read the response of the POST directly, as it happens in the IFRAME and has another domain than the host page.

But if you need a feedback of the request, your bookmarklet can use `setInterval` to poll every X milliseconds and ask the status of the request, using [JSONP](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/).

Calling something like:
`http://yourdomain.com/get-post-status?id=2234234&callback=showResult`